# hartl chapter 5 full_title not found

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm in the Hartl tutorial in Chapter 5.
I'm getting the following error when running the test file:

Failures:

```
1) User pages Signup page 
 Failure/Error: it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
 NoMethodError:
   undefined method `full_title' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_2::Nested_1:0xaeb792c>
 # ./spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:12:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

For brevity, I've commented out the other "full_title not found" errors while troubleshooting.

I've confirmed that the method is in the app/helpers/application_helper.rb file.
Any ideas why it's not being found?   It's most definitely in the helper file.

My user pages spec file:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "User pages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "Signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1',    text: 'Sign Up') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: full_title('Sign up')) }
  end
end
```

and my application_helper.rb file

```
module ApplicationHelper

  # Returns the full title on a per-page basis.
  def full_title(page_title)
    base_title = "Ruby on Rails Tutorial Sample App"
    if page_title.empty?
      base_title
    else
      "#{base_title} | #{page_title}"
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/filling-in-the-layout#sec-user_signup) seems to add that in a different place that yours. The `full_title` used on the `spec` was defined on `spec/support/utilities.rb`. The one defined on the `application_helper.rb` was used in `app/views/layouts/application.html.erb`.

Comment: Thank you so much.  I'm not sure how I missed that.  I've literally been looking at this for hours.  That took care of my problems.